# are lists of list pass by reference in python when they are created by multiplication?

Tags: python, list, reference

I was just playing around with python, take this code:

```
a=[[-1,-1,-1],[-1,-1,-1],[-1,-1,-1]]
b=[[-1]*3]*3
print(a)
print(b)
a[0][0]=6
b[0][0]=6
print(a)
print(b)
```

As I would expected it, both lists most be the same at the end, but they don´t, it looks like doing `[[-1]*3]*3` creates by reference the lists, you can see that all first values from the list are change
On console:

```
[[-1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, -1]]
[[-1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, -1]]
[[6, -1, -1], [-1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, -1]]
[[6, -1, -1], [6, -1, -1], [6, -1, -1]]
```

is it a bug or is it just a normal behaviour?
I'm using python 3.7

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly).

Comment: thanks! I tried to look for it on stackoverflow but I didn't find it, I wouldn't find it anyway with that title :D